# I have some svg rectangles. Is it possible to adjust the size as per screen size?

Tags: css, svg

I have some svg rectangles. Is it possible to adjust the size as per screen size? Currently it looks fine on smaller screen but on the bigger screen the rectangles dont take up whole space.

Comment: use a viewBox to do that

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Robert - Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport units in CSS.

`100vw` = 100% screen width

`100vh` = 100% screen height

Those values can be any percent of the screen.

Mixed with `calc()`, this can get you almost anything you could want.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.